# Binding error in design and runtime on usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, windows-forms-designer

In great need help with the strange binding problem with regards to Winform UserControls.

Its like this.

- Have a form with a UserControl
- UserControl has a System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource control
- BindingSource has a DataSource set to an entity POCO type at design time.
- UserControl has controls that are bound to properties on the POCO class. An example: *CreateDate*

No problem in designer of the UserControl itself.

But entering the designer og the Form containing the UserControl, I get a designer error window with the message: "Cannot bind to the property or column CreateDate on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember"

In runtime I get the same error, but first when Show is called on the form. Here I can see on the stack trace that it is thrown after a CheckBinding call.

The error occurs no matter if the DataSource on the bindingSource is set or not during the creation (in constructor) or Load event on the form.

I can see that the designer sets my data source like this in the designer file: **this.bindingSourceRecipe.DataSource = typeof(Data.Entities.Recipe);**

I have tried so many things to solve this problem. It seems very strange as this is a dead simple form/control setup and should be a trivial use of Winforms usercontrols.

If I set the bindingSourceRecipe.DataSource at runtime to a temp. instance just after the InitializeComponent() in the form then no error occure;

```
InitializeComponent();
ucRecipeBaseControl.Recipe = new Recipe() { Id = 0, CreateDate = DateTime.Now, Name = "" };
```

So it seems that the Initialization cycle of the form/control somehow clears the binding source knowledge about its DataSource type.

This does of course not happen if a place all the user controls and BindingSource Directly on the form. Then everythings works, and it does not matter if the DataSource ever gets set to an instance of a Data entity.

Seems like a complete mystery to me, should be dead simple, and I'm kind of lost on what to do.

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

BR Peter Meldgaard

Comment: Ahhh, got it nailed at last. It was caused by a mix of Winform designer behavior and my code. I was setting the binding controls datasource in a public property setter, so I could save a copy of the entity, to be able to compare the changed and the org.
The thing is that when you put a control with a public property on a form, then the designer inthis property to null inside the designer generated code. I did not know that. So everytime the usercontrol was instantiated, the DataSource got set to null, clearing the typeof(dataentity), and the loosing the binding information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhh, got it nailed at last. It was caused by a mix of Winform designer behavior and my code. I was setting the binding controls datasource in a public property setter, so I could save a copy of the entity, to be able to compare the changed and the org. The thing is that when you put a control with a public property on a form, then the designer initializes this property to null inside the designer generated code. I did not know that. So everytime the usercontrol was instantiated, the DataSource got set to null, clearing the typeof(dataentity), albeit loosing the binding information.

Adding a null check in the setter, and only update datasource when value is not null fixed the issue.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if you can explain, in more detail and with some example, how you solved this problem. I have the same situation that arises here but I can't understand your answer.